# Test ASP.NET application for Windows Authentication for user which is not in domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am working on a ASP.NET application which uses Windows Authentication. It works fine with users who are in Active Directory. Each page of application has been accessed by different users which are assigned roles with SQLRoleProvider. My question is how can I test my application for users who are not in domain? Can I pass  fake user name and password from my code to test it?

Please help me with this.

Is there is any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you just create a minimal-privileged domain user for testing purposes? If you're using Windows Auth, you should probably test your app against a Windows user.

Comment: actually creating a user is not in my hand its on network administrators.. that's why I want to do it from code

Comment: I understand, but have you asked your network admins to create the user for you and explain what it's used for? Otherwise, you can use your own account, but that's not ideal, or change the auth type, but then your testing suffers because of the difference between dev and production.

Comment: My application was using forms authentication before but now we need to change it to Windows. I will try to ask my admin about that. Please let me know if you know some other option than that. Thank you for your help.:) I really appreciate it

Comment: You could also conceivably hack your own IPrincipal and set it in an IHttpModule that is only used in dev or something, but (as you may be beginning to sense) the easiest approach is probably just to create the test user. The practice is common, and you can emphasize to your admin that it doesn't need any permissions or setup other than what is required by your app.

Comment: Yeah I have tried so may different ways but nothing is working. I will ask them to do it. Thank You:)

Comment: @Colin: Just a quick one, so the one you mentioned in the previous comment can be done through the Global.asax file, right?

Comment: Yes, though you couldn't just turn Global.asax off with a configuration change like you could a standalone IHttpModule.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a test-only login page to facilitate what you are trying to do, rather than work around windows authentication?  I've also found ways to do this through the application code, depending on how easy or complicated the setup is.

Comment: Test-only page? Do I need to disable windows authentication for that?